I got scammed by a person who claimed to be a girl in Singapore
I was contacted from a girl of Singapore,she told me to join a website,with 866 of buying USDT erc-20,every day I withdraw 30 dollar,but today I accept this partecipation for the claim the reward but nowhere was written that one time you accept if you don’t put the rest of money in my case 3633, they blocked for 180 days my money, how I to reclaim my money, I contact them from the customer service of the website and send me to a telegram number service and they say I had to wait 180 days if I don’t put the rest of the money,what I have to do for to take back my 866 USDT ? Help me
I believe this is managed by someone knows me locally, I am residing in UAE-Abu Dhabi, how can I report that ? Who is the website owner for ERC-20 smart contract ? Who can help me ? Shall I report it to the local authorities ?
